# Trying to make a column with a range from a pre-exisitng column. - SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, plsql

I have a column with random data that ranges from (0 to n), 
I want to select it so that I get a new column that goes up in increments of 5.
so 0 - 5, 5 - 10, so on and so forth.

Current Table:-

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Hello |
| 5 | Hello2 |
| 8 | Hello3 |

Expected Table:-

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 - 5 | Hello2 |
| 6 - 10 | Hello, Hello3 |

Everything I've tried doesn't really give a dynamic answer.

Comment: show us your attempt

Comment: It's just using case then, which is good for a static table but in this case it scales, so needed a dynamic solution.

Comment: If we have `8` in `ColumnA`, what is the expected result?

Comment: Also : maybe `0-5` should be `0-4`, and `6-10` should be `5-9` or `10-14`?

Comment: @GMB it should be based on the incremental value as mentioned, like 
the first value will be 0, and the end value will be let's say 100, and the incremental value is 5, so 0 -5, 6 -10, 11 -15, 16 - 20, so on so forth, and the 8 value for which the corresponding column B value will go under 6 - 10 category.

Comment: tsql and plsql are contradictory tags. What is your DBMS really?

Comment: @ketanmaurya: ok, so the first interval should be `1-5`, not `0-5` (otherwise there are 6 elements in the interval, which is not consistent really).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use arithmetics.  Assuming a table like so:

```
create table t(id int, name varchar(100));
insert into t values (5, 'Hello2'), (8, 'Hello3'), (10, 'Hello');
```

We can compute the lower bound of the interval with this expression:

```
select t.*, 1 + (id - 1) / 5 * 5 lbound from mytable
```

| id | name | lbound |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Hello2 | 1 |
| 8 | Hello3 | 6 |
| 10 | Hello | 6 |

The `+1/-1` gym is there because we want intervals that start at `1` rather than `0`. With this information at hand, we can easily compute the upper bound (just `+4` to the lower bound), and aggregate.

If you are running SQL Server (you tagged the question `tsql`):

```
select x.lbound, x.lbound + 4 ubound, 
    string_agg(t.name, ', ') within group(order by t.id) names
from t
cross apply ( values ( 1 + (t.id - 1) / 5 * 5) ) x(lbound)
group by x.lbound
```

| lbound | ubound | names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | Hello2 |
| 6 | 10 | Hello3, Hello |

Comment: Better with the CROSS APPLY  ...  +1